# d3js Nodes from Links json

Tags: json, d3.js

I have the following json:

```
"Links": [

{"Source": "A","Target": "B","Value": "10000"},
{"Source": "A","Target": "C","Value": "10000"},
{"Source": "B","Target": "D","Value": "10000"}
]
```

how can i extract unique nodes name to use them in a d3js force layout graph.

Trying to adapt http://plnkr.co/edit/20t4F02vsM1U55ktCv66?p=preview .

Many thanks,

Marv

Comment: Why do you need unique node names? It works fine if you just replace the JSON: http://plnkr.co/edit/yOgqvlL7abFYnK7SuI5e?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try as shown below.

```js
var graph = { 
  "Links": [
   {"Source": "A","Target": "B","Value": "10000"},
   {"Source": "A","Target": "C","Value": "10000"},
   {"Source": "B","Target": "D","Value": "10000"}
  ] 
};

var nodeArr = graph.Links.map(function(d){ return [d.Source,d.Target] }).join().split(",");
var uniqueNodeArr = nodeArr.filter(function(d,i){ return nodeArr.indexOf(d)==i });

graph['Nodes'] = uniqueNodeArr.map(function(node,i){ return { name: node, id: i }; });
graph['Links'] = graph['Links'].map(function(l){ 
  var link = {};
  link['source'] = uniqueNodeArr.indexOf(l.Source); 
  link['target'] = uniqueNodeArr.indexOf(l.Target);
  link['value'] = l.Value;
  return link;
});

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("svg:defs").append("svg:marker")
    .attr("id", "arrow")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

  force
      .nodes(graph.Nodes)
      .links(graph.Links)
      .linkDistance(60)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.Links)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", "2")
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");;

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.Nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "node");

  node.append("circle")      
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill","red")
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("d", function(d) { return "M"+d.source.x+","+d.source.y+" L"+d.target.x+","+d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"; });
  });
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}
text{
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```